# Reading lines of a file into a subprocess in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, nmap

So I'm trying to read a list of IP addresses from a .txt into a subprocess (Nmap) in Python.  It's also worth asking if the problem could be the use of quotes or not.  Here's the code:

```
addressFile = raw_input("Input the name of the IP address list file.  File must be in current directory." )
fileObj = open(addressFile, 'r')


for line in fileObj:
    strLine = str(line)
    command = raw_input("Please enter your Nmap scan." )
    formatCom = shlex.split(command)
    subprocess.check_output([formatCom, strLine])
```

Trusty error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mod2hw7.py", line 15, in <module>
    subprocess.check_output([formatCom, strLine])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Comment: By the way, `strLine = str(line)` is unnecessary. `line` is already a string. Also, you should open the file with a context manager: `with open(addressFile) as input_file:` Then on the next line: `for line in input_file:`

Comment: Lots of problems can be sorted out simply by printing out the parameters of the failing command. Try `print ([formatCom, strLine])` and see if it looks right.

Comment: unrelated: `nmap` can read ips from a file itself, use `-iL <file>` option: `subprocess.check_call(formatCom + ['-iL', addressFile])`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, the printing the failing command tip was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) returns a list; you should catenate this list with 1 element list containing `strline` when building command line arguments:

```
formatCom = shlex.split(command)
subprocess.check_output(formatCom + [strLine])
```

---

The error occurs because instead of

```
subprocess.check_output([ 'nmap', '-sT', '8.8.8.8' ])
```

you are executing something like

```
subprocess.check_output([ ['nmap', '-sT'], '8.8.8.8' ])
```

and `subprocess` expects to be given a list of strings, not nested lists.

Comment: The line also needs to have its new-line stripped (and casting it to string is unnecessary) so... `[line.strip()]` works better.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, that was exactly what I was hoping for!